# How to make a heatmap with horizontal rects?

Tags: r, ggvis

How can I change the width and height of rectangles in a heatmap such that the short side will be perpendicular to the horizontal axis?

I thought something like this would work but it didn't

```
tbl_df(iris) %>%
  ggvis(~ Species, ~Species) %>% 
layer_rects(fill= ~Petal.Width, width = band(), height = band(mult=.25))
```

Comment: I'm not getting anything happening with the arguments to `band`.

Comment: There is an open github issue about `band` arguments not doing anything [here](https://github.com/rstudio/ggvis/issues/408)